# How to interpret the symbol $L( \frac{1}{2}, \pi \times \chi)$?

Tags: modular-forms, l-functions, adeles

I am trying to interpret the symbol $L( \frac{1}{2}, \pi \times \chi)$ where $\chi = \mathbb{A}^\times / \mathbb{Q}^\times$ and $\pi$ is a cuspidal representation of $GL_2( \mathbb{A})$  (where $\mathbb{A}$ are the adeles over $\mathbb{Q}$), something like 
$$ \mathbb{A} = \prod' \mathbb{Q}_p $$

where we use a "restricted" product in order to avoid axiom of choice difficulties<\del>.

I was told cusp forms match *cuspidal representations* of $GL(2, \mathbb{A})$   Let me write down a cusp form:

$$ \theta(z; u) = \sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} (a^2 - b^2) \,e^{2\pi i (a^2 + b^2 ) \, z}$$

and I can even write down the L-function without too much thought

$$ L(\tfrac{1}{2}, \pi \times \chi) =  \sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2} =? \, 0$$

It might not even be correct.

---

Since $u(a,b)=a^2-b^2$ is a harmonic polynomial in two variables, the theta function I have written should be a modular form on $\Gamma_0(4)$ of weight $2+1/2+1/2=3$.   And it should be a cusp form. Not 100% sure about $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain more how did u obtain your L value formula "without too much thought"? Where is chi in your formula?

Comment: @QingZhang $\chi \equiv 1$ identically.  Part of my question is to write out $\pi$.

Comment: Could u explain more on your last formula?

Comment: Why is the right side convergent?

Comment: @QingZhang Like I said I didn't put much thought, but then I really don't understand the definition of the automorphic L-function.

Comment: If you want to figure out the cuspidal representation pi, you might have to look at gelbart's book on automorphic representation. If my memory is correct, if a cusp form is given by sum a_n e^｛2pi i ns｝, then its L function is the sum of a_n/n^s when Re(s) large. It takes some effort to continue it to the whole plane. From the automorphic representation point of view, the L function is an Euler product of local L functions over all places and at each place the local L function is certain GCD of a family of local zeta integrals. You might want to read some Cogdell's notes.

Comment: This question is absolute gibberish. Let me make some comments.

Comment: 1) I'm guessing $\chi$ is supposed to be a Hecke character, that is a continuous group homomorphism $\chi : \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which is the same thing (essentially) as a Dirichlet character.

Comment: 2) It is not true that $\mathbb{A} = \prod' \mathbb{Z}_p$; rather, it is the restricted product of local fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$, with "restricted" meaning that an element $(x_{\infty},x_2,x_3,x_5,\ldots,x_p,\ldots)$ of $\mathbb{A}$ is such that $x_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$ for all but finitely many primes $p$. This has nothing to do with the axiom of choice.

Comment: 3) The function $\theta(z;u)$ that you've written down is not a cusp form. Moreover, any $L$-function is only defined for newforms: these are cusp forms of integral weight (not half-integral weight, like theta functions!) that are eigenfunctions of every Hecke operator.

Comment: 4) The "$L$-function" you've written down is utter gibberish. Again, $L$-functions are associated to Hecke eigenforms. Moreover, an $L$-function $L(s,f)$ of a newform with Hecke eigenvalues $\lambda_f(n)$ has $L$-function defined to be $L(s,f) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_f(n) n^{-s}$ for $\Re(s) > 1$, and extended to the complex plane via analytic continuation. This does not just mean that you can let $s = 1/2$ and expect the sum to converge!

Comment: In any case, you really need to spend more time reading books on automorphic forms (Iwaniec's, Diamond-Shurman, Apostol, etc.), in order to get a grasp on the basics.

Comment: @peterhumphries the only way I can learn is by reading and asking questions.. The textbook I am trying to use is **Automorphic Forms** by Anton Deitmar.. He says you can turn any modular form $f(z)=\sum a_n \, q^n$ into an L-series  $L(s,f)=\sum a_n \, n^{-s}$ and try to make sense of it.  Certainly Hecke eigenform is too restrictive. The $\theta(z;u)$ I have written should be a cusp form on $\Gamma_0(4)$ of weight $2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=3$.

Comment: @cactus314, apologies, $\theta(z;u)$ is indeed a cusp form (Theorem 10.8 of Iwaniec, "Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms"). As for $L$-functions: sure, you can associate a Dirichlet $L$-*series* to any automorphic form, which will be a linear combination of $L$-functions of newforms. It's not a very natural thing to do, though.

Comment: In your case, we can write $\theta(z;u) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_f(n) e(nz)$ with $a_f(n)$ equal to the sum of $a^2 - b^2$ over all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ for which $a^2 + b^2 = n$. The resulting Dirichlet series is indeed $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_f(n) n^{-s} = \sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} (a^2 - b^2) (a^2 + b^2)^{-s}$, which is well-defined for $\Re(s) > 1$, but needs to be written as a linear combination of $L$-functions of Hecke eigenforms in order to have an analytic continuation to the left of the line $\Re(s) = 1$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I haven't even read carefully the part about Hecke Operators yet :-) First of all, there's an extensive theory of Dirichlet series, and we could try to continue left of that line.  Deitmar proves a functional equation for all $L(f,s)$ where $f$ is any integer-weight cusp form.  And in the next section he develops the Hecke operators.

Comment: @cactus314, I guess my underlying point is that the $L$-series is arithmetically uninteresting (i.e. the coefficients aren't multiplicative, so there's no Euler product) unless the modular form is an eigenfunction of every Hecke operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{2i \pi nz} \in M_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ then $$f \otimes \chi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \chi(n) e^{2i \pi nz} =\frac{1}{q} \sum_{m=1}^q \hat{\chi(m)} f(z+\frac{m}{q}) \in M_k(\Gamma_0(N q^2),\chi^2)$$ for any primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q$, where $ \hat{\chi(m)} = \sum_{n=1}^q \chi(n) e^{-2i \pi nm/q} = \overline{\chi(m)} \hat{\chi(1)}=\overline{\chi(m)}G(\chi)$. For $\chi$ non-primitive $\hat{\chi(m)}$ is more complicated (not completely multiplicative) and hence $f \otimes \chi$ is only modular for $\Gamma_1(N q^2)$.

> Proof : for $\gamma = {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\  cNq^2 & d \end{pmatrix}} \in \Gamma_0(Nq^2)$ and $T^{m/q} = {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{m}q\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}$ then  $T^{m/q} \gamma T^{-d^2 m/q} =\gamma_m \in \Gamma_0(Nq^2)$. Thus $f \otimes \chi|_k \gamma (z)$ $=\frac{1}{q} \sum_{m=1}^q \hat{\chi(m)} f |_k T^{m/q}\gamma (z)=\frac{1}{q} \sum_{m=1}^q \hat{\chi(m)} f|_k \gamma_m T^{d^2 m/q} (z)$ $=\frac{1}{q} \sum_{m=1}^q \hat{\chi(m)} f|_k T^{d^2 m/q} (z)= \ldots$

You can interpret $f \mapsto f \otimes \chi$ as a double coset operator, similar to the Hecke operators.

For automorphic representations, the meaning is the same, except we can interpret it as a tensor product of representations (looking first at twists of Artin L-functions is easier).

See also the Rankin-Selberg convolution, allowing to twist by any automorphic representation/L-function.

Comment: do you have a name or e-mail ? i could try to respond here. what Automorphic representations correspond to spherical harmonics?

Comment: does the Dirichlet series in this question have a representation as an automorphic form? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570742/what-is-the-domain-of-convergence-for-sum-a-b-in-mathbbz2-fraca4 fortunately your twist works for any series

Comment: i still have no idea what an automorphic form is so $f \otimes \chi $ is a better object for me, since i manipulate the series.